# Flatten OpenCV/Numpy Array

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I've loaded an RGB image with PIL/OpenCV, and I'd like convert all its channels into a single 1x(3*width*height) sequence into order to feed it to an ANN. I found I can simply do:

```
rlist = []
glist = []
blist = []
for i in xrange(im.width):
    for j in xrange(im.height):
        r,g,b = im[i,j]
        rlist.append(r)
        glist.append(g)
        blist.append(b)
img_vec = rlist + blist + glist
```

But obviously this is horribly inefficient. Is there a faster way with some internal OpenCV/numpy routine?

Comment: ANN == artificial neural network

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a quick example:

```
import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('temp.png')
data = np.array(im)
flattened = data.flatten()

print data.shape
print flattened.shape
```

This yields:

```
(612, 812, 4)
(1987776,)
```

Alternately, instead of calling `data.flatten()`, you could call `data.reshape(-1)`.  `-1` is used as a placeholder for "figure out what the given dimension should be".

Note that this will yield a vector (`flattened`) of `r0, g0, b0, r1, g1, b1, ... rn, gn, bn`, while you want a vector of `r0, r1 ... rn, b0, b1, ... bn, g0, g1, ... gn`.

To get exactly what you want, just call

```
flattened = data.T.flatten()
```

instead.

Comment: Are you sure about data.T.flatten()? My tests show that data.flatten() returns the data in order [r1,r2...,g1,g2,...b1,b2...] whereas data.T.flatten() returns it in order [r1,g1,b1,r2,g2,b2,...]. However, I tested using simple numpy arrays, not actual images.